# Can all Blackberry devices upgrade to the latest firmware?

Tags: sqlite, mobile, blackberry

I've been reading about the OS on BlackBerry and one of its latest updates, SQLite, introduced with the v5.0 OS.

Can all BlackBerry phones upgrade to this OS? I have a BlackBerry Storm 9500 from Orange (France) and I can [download a simulator](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp) for this phone with 5.0 OS on, but the device itself wont update past v4.7 OS. Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are international versions that don't go beyond 4.x. The latest version of the OS is 6.

So there are several generations of BB's which typically fall into one of the following Operating Systems:

- 4.6.0.x (Some older phones)
- 5.0.0.x (Most recent phones)
- 6.0.0.x (Latest phones)

The blackberry site [hosts a great page](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp) to find out what versions of the OS is available for individual phones.